# Converting element types of python lists in Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of values, in string format (because that's what they're read in as from the CSV source):

```
[ '12.2', '14.5', '13.8', '17.3', '14.9' ]
```

In my Jinja2 template, I would like to do the functional equivalent of:

```
The average is: {{list|average}}
```

This is being done inside a loop, so simply calculating one average inside python and passing it to the Jinja2 template isn't as feasible as it should be. Is there an easy way to do this? Should I create a custom filter that handles the string->float conversion? Should I bite the bullet and calculate averages of lists inside Python before rendering the template?

Answer (score 0):

create a function in python file

```
def average(values):
    float_value = [float(val) for val in values]
    return sum(float_value) / len(float_value)
```

then import as follow

```
 {% import '--.py' as value%}
 The average is: {{list|value.average}}
```